# GWT dynamic data in new browser window at client side

Tags: gwt, browser, window, new-operator

I've got GWT module where I do some stuff and I have search results - doesn't matter in which form. Now after searching, and clicking on for example "Export to HTML" button,I would like to create new html page (for example from client side code by creating simple string which contains only listed results of searching  list of results ) and open it in new browser window. I know that there is Window.open(...) method, but there I must specify url which i don't have. I want to create this new html page by client side - without server inference (I don't want to create some resource on server side and then paste url to this resource to client side). Is there any possibility to achieve this? If there is no option, other method which would satisfy me, is to open standard dialog box for saving, which will allow to save results in a html file.

Thanks for helps.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code I use to print:

```
native void openPrintWindow(String contents) /*-{
    var printWindow = window.open("", "PrintWin");
    if (printWindow && printWindow.top) {
        printWindow.document.write(contents);
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    } else {
        alert("The print feature works by opening a popup window, but our popup window was blocked by your browser.  If you can disable the blocker temporarily, you'll be able to print here.  Sorry!");
    }
}-*/;
```

Seems like you could adapt it for your purposes with some simple rewording and by removing the call to print()!  The `contents` variable just holds flat HTML.  There are no trips to the server.

```
openPrintWindow("<h1>Search Results</h1><ol><li>etc...");
```

Comment: This works great, but I have one question: when I click button "Export to HTML" everything is ok (new html page with search results is open) but in the title bar of the new browser tab is "Connecting..." text all the time. I can save my new page without any problems, but this "Connecting..." is little annoying. Have you any idea what is going on? The url in the new tab is this one which I use to connect to my whole GWT module, so maybe this module is loading in the background (but there is small possibility of that - in eclipse development mode I don't have any info about loading module)Thanks

Comment: This was happening to me too - I added `printWindow.close()` (see edited answer) and everything was peachy.

Answer (score 0):

The method of opening new window from client js which allows user to save that generated content from browser's save as menu is data:url scheme, content written to opened page via println usualy not saved. But data:url works only in morden browsers. And the content written should be quite small to fit browser's url length resteiction.

See example from this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for reply, I used Riley solution.